# React data grid does not always show values on the last few columns

Tags: react-data-grid

The smaller my screen size is, the more columns will not have values.  As soon as I adjust the width of my screen manually (by dragging it larger or smaller), all the values will show up.  This seems like a bug.  I've attached 2 photos showing how the html shows up on adjacent cells with a value and without a value showing.

[One cell showing value the next not showing value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5wnb.png) | 
[Before I drag the window size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn5Ih.png)

```
getGridProps: ->
    { budgets } = @props.profile
    rowHeight = headerHeight = 35
    extraHeightToPreventScrollBar = 10
    rowsCount = budgets?.length ? 0

    columns: @getColumns()
    rowGetter: (i) =>
        budgetRows = @getBudgetRows()
        budgetRows[i]
    rowsCount: rowsCount
    minHeight: rowsCount * rowHeight + headerHeight + extraHeightToPreventScrollBar
    enableCellSelect: not @state.tableDisabled
    onGridRowsUpdated: @handleGridRowsUpdated


getColumns: ->
    cols = [{ key: 'year', name: 'Year', editable: false, width: 70 }]
    for month in MONTHS
        cols.push
            key: month
            name: month
            editable: not @state.tableDisabled
            formatter: FormattedCell
    cols.push
        key: 'total'
        name: 'Total'
        editable: false
        formatter: FormattedCell
    cols.push
        key: 'trash'
        name: ''
        editable: false
        formatter: getTrashCan @removeBudget, @state.tableDisabled
        width: 50

    cols

getBudgetRows: ->
    { budgets } = @props.profile
    _.map budgets, (monthlyBudgets) ->
        row = { year: monthlyBudgets.year }
        for month, monthIdx in MONTHS
            row[month] = monthlyBudgets.budgets[monthIdx] ? '' # ReactDataGrid cannot take null, convert to ''
        row.total = Util.getBudgetsTotal monthlyBudgets ? ''
        row.trash = monthlyBudgets.year
        row
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution we found is to add minColumnWidth: 10 to the gridProps